# How to achieve absolute fastest way when doing COUNT(*) GROUP BY string

Tags: mysql, sql

I will have a relatively large growing dataset with 250M+ rows with a very basic table structure:

`id (unsigned int primary)`, `age (tinyint)`, `email (some type of string)`

where I will be performing `count(*)` queries based on `age` grouped by `email`. For example:

```
select count(*) as count from table 
where age = 38
group by email
order by count
limit 100
```

`email` field is going to be up to 60 chars.

I don't need the very precise results so I will be fine with approximate results as long as the queries run as fast as possible. So I am open for smart tricks and maybe even funny approaches.

Apart from choosing the correct data type for `email` and indexing `age` and `email` together what other tricks could help?

For example, if the `email` size was going to be larger than 32 chars on average, I would have stored the md5 hash instead. Furthermore, I could get rid of `@` and `.` from the `email` as I don't care a few emails ending up colliding with each other (abc@xyz.com and ab@cxyz.com would be both abcxyzcom and it is fine). Also, I thought maybe compressing the `email` field could be an option.

Comment: What are the timings you're getting now?

Comment: I am just starting up, so I don't have any at the moment. Just want to have a good set up from the beginning. I will use the table extensively, the better results I achieve, I can run more queries with the available resources.

Comment: @Drew I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: You have 1 table, with 3 columns. That is it. It doesn't exist in the context of other tables, or an app, or anything. It just is. It just seems to get bigger. There is nothing else whatsoever going on.

Comment: That's not the whole table. I simplified it and left the relevant parts only before putting it here.

Comment: How often and how live do you need the data?

Comment: @Drew what is the matter with you? Do you want me to post here the whole project? I am just seeking advice at the basic level. Is my question not clear? Ask me to clarify if you have any questions. Does it matter how long have I been around answering questions?

Comment: @michael It does not matter much how live the data is but I will probably need it as often as once every couple of minutes.

Comment: there is nothing the matter with me. Give us the context of how data flows in your system, so we can craft the fastest solution for you. Obfuscate the rest of it, well, what do you expect

Comment: if you want my advice, never do what you are suggesting. Have your answer at your finger tips. So that satisifies the **How to achieve absolute fastest** part of it. But you and I will never get there (probably fine with both of us), because all you have is 1 table with 3 columns. Heading off to other questions. Good luck, seriously.

Comment: You need an advice as well: Be nice. And deleting the ugly comment you wrote to this conversation does not make you nice, you should not write them in the first place.

Comment: How many unique emails do you expect to have in 250M rows?  Sidebar - why are you grouping by email?  It seems possible that you're encountering this issue because of a failure to properly normalize.

Comment: @DanField I expect to have up to 500K unique emails. Yes, this table would definitely benefit from normalization but I didn't prefer to check an email lookup table each time before inserting data. Plus, this way it is more flexible which I might need later on.

Comment: advice received, well deserved, thanks. Let me know if you need my help someday with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I moved forward. As I mentioned I don't need the very precise results and I will be fine with approximate results as long as the queries run as fast as possible.

So I defined email field as `bigint` (8 bytes, small size, fast operations) and saved the emails using the function `hex( substr( md5( email), 4, 8 ) )` I checked it with the list of 700K email addresses and there were only 17 pair of emails which was colliding with each other. So with 0.004% error margin, I could be able run aggregate functions very fast.

Thanks for the insights.

PS. I tried substring function with different `pos` vars. Starting from position 4 seemed like causing the least colliding emails after the md5 hash.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your table is poorly designed (denormalized in a way that's going to hurt performance instead of help it), and should be refactored into two or more tables.  While denormalization might make some things easier, it's going to make this query that you need to refresh every two minutes very expensive - no matter how you do it.

If you really do have a good reason to keep the table denormalized (and that reason isn't just "it'll make inserts harder"), you'll likely still need a pseudo-normalized table that only contains unique email addresses.  There you could either keep a numeric ID for each email address and foreign key that back to your original table (which you're trying to avoid), or have th email address itself be the primary key and a column that you insert or update to reflect the count for that email address.  Whenever you insert into the original table, you also insert (with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause) into that email tracking table.

My bet is that it would be better to just normalize your original table than pursue this, but it is an option.  It seems likely that you're issue isn't so much that email addresses are denormalized, but that user account information is denormalized - do you really allow different users to have the same email?  If you're trying to report on how many users of a particular age perform a certain action, there should be a better key to use than the email address - like a numeric user id perhaps, or a table to track the count of actions for a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dan. But the literal answer to your problem would be to leave your query and table as is and make sure you have a non clustered index on email that also has age  or INCLUDES the age field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for data which is being loaded from 3rd party system then I would suggest design a summary table and run your query and cache your results in summary table periodically. For example you can run query against this table every hour and feed your summary table which stores email, count and age if you want. I am just assuming that you would want to store statistics for other age groups too. I am suggesting summary table because you do not need accurate data. This way you will be able to render your reports on screen much faster by loading statistics from summary table.

Summary table could have columns like:

```
- age_group
- email
- count
```

or may be just

```
- email 
- count
```

I am not sure what data are you trying to pull but I would want to see count of email by age_group and not by email. So I would have following two columns in my summary table:

```
- age_group
- count_of_email
```

So I know what is the age-group of users I have in my system.